# How come this method does not open up a file and write to it?

Tags: java

I made this method and my goal is to populate a txt file of name filename with the elements that are contained in arrayToWrite, but it does not seem to be working. Does the file get deleted once the method ends? because that is my main issue it would seem my other method can not print the content that is in the file made by this method.

```
public static void writeFile(String[] arrayToWrite, String filename) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    PrintWriter outFS = new PrintWriter(fileStream);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToWrite.length; i++) {
        outFS.println(arrayToWrite[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to close file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `outFS.close()` to the end of your function.

Comment: Using try-with-resources is the best practice to simplify this without needing to add explicit close calls.

Answer (score 1):

You may declare one or more resources in a try-with-resources statement and both `FileOutputStream` class and `PrintWriter` class implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, so to solve your problem you can write :

```
public static void writeFile(String[] arrayToWrite, String filename) throws IOException {
    try (
      FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
      PrintWriter outFS = new PrintWriter(fileStream)
    ) {  

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToWrite.length; i++) {
            outFS.println(arrayToWrite[i]);
        }

    }
}
```